Manual variable selection in GAM model based in deviance explained
I'm fitting a generalized additive model (GAM) to predict bottlenecks in a manufacturing process of a company. They have data of the bottlenecks that occurs in their process of making hot steel rolls. The bottlenecks only occur in two places, so I'm fitting a logistic GAM model. I have plenty of variables and I want to know which of these variables are important to the bottlenecks to occur. My procedure is based on adding variables one by one and seeing how the percentage of explained deviance changes, since for some variables the percentage of explained deviance remains practically the same and only with some does this percentage rise a little. Is this a correct method?
PD: I chose a GAM model because the process expert told me that in this process there are non-linear relationships.

I would recommend looking at how predicted probabilities change when new variables are added.  You want your model to a) discriminate well, and b) have good calibration.  Take a look at this post by Frank Harrell for more https://www.fharrell.com/post/addvalue/

And keep in mind that variable selection is usually a bad idea.  It doesn't work.

@FrankHarrell I think the typical methods like stepwise, etc. are not ideal if we are fitting theoretical models, but would the same be true if our sole goal is prediction only? I'm guessing there is still a balance to be had there, else Simon Wood wouldn't have included the select argument in mgcv. As I recall, mgcv uses a penalty-based approach similar to ridge/lasso.

Feature selection is also bad for prediction in that the uncertainty intervals for predicted values are too narrow (false confidence) and predictive discrimination is not as good as using a smooth shrinkage method such as ridge regression.  The attempt to "name names" i.e. achieve parsimony results in information loss and arbitrariness.

Prediction is not the primary goal here. The company seeks to understand why bottlenecks occur. They have an idea why based on expert knowledge, but by installing sensors throughout their manufacturing process they collected a lot of data and wanted to obtain a point of view from data analysis

Since your goal is more prediction than theory, I don't necessarily see the issue with adding more values and checking their associated AIC/BIC values with each fit.
What would probably be more helpful, if you have a fair amount of data, is to perform some form or cross-validation, where you fit about 80% of the data to the model (the training data) and then predict new values with the other 20% (the test data). This can give you an idea of whether or not your more complex models predict new values better than more basic models. Indeed, often fitting more variables may have better explained variance, etc. but may be so overfit that it does a poor job of prediction on new values. Testing it on prediction data would elucidate whatever problems exist there.
One can also just visually inspect the data to see if some variables are truly useless. If you find one variable is statistically significant but has an extremely low effect size, then one can simply omit it if it seems irrelevant to the task at hand.
